# How I can change the starting coordinates with user coordinates?

Tags: html, api, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I'm working on a program that takes latitude and longitude and generates nearby locations based on search queries. Everything's working as intended, but I'm at a loss on how I can change the starting coordinates with user coordinates. My initial plan was to have the user enter a lat and lng in the following form:

```
<form id="mapCenterForm">
    <label for="latitude">lat</label>
    <input type="text" id="lat" name="latitude" placeholder="0.000000">

    <label for="longitude">lng</label>
    <input type="text" id="lng" name="longitude" placeholder="0.000000">
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then used the information entered to change the variables lat, and lng in the script:

```
  var map;
  var lat= 34.16076;
  var lng= -70.20507;
  var map=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

      function initMap() {
        // Create the map.
        var SET = {lat, lng};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: SET,
          zoom: 10
        });
```

But I don't know if there's a means of replacing lat and lng that the map loads as a starting point.

Sorry if this is similar to a few other problems posted, I tried using [Changing latitude and longitude google maps api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107788/changing-latitude-and-longitude-google-maps-api#36115921) for guidance, but it didn't help much for me.

---

EDIT: I'm adding a complete piece of HTML code, as I received an answer, and did some editing, but it's not actually changing the SET variable. Hopefully people will be able to run this, as to better understand the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Base Mapper</title>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #right-panel {
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }

      #right-panel select, #right-panel input {
        font-size: 15px;
      }

      #right-panel select {
        width: 100%;
      }

      #right-panel i {
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      #right-panel {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
        top: 60%;
        margin-top: -395px;
        height: 650px;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 5px;
        z-index: 5;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        background: #fff;
      }
      h2 {
        font-size: 22px;
        margin: 0 0 5px 0;
      }
      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 580px;
        width: 200px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
      li {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        padding: 5px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      li:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #fcfcfc;
      }
      #more {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 5px 0 0 0;
      }
          input[type=text], select {
              width: 100%;
              padding: 12px 20px;
              margin: 8px 0;
              display: inline-block;
              border: 1px solid #ccc;
              border-radius: 4px;
              box-sizing: border-box;
          }

          .container {
              border-radius: 5px;
              background-color: #f2f2f2;
              padding: 20px;
              width:70%
          }

    </style>
    <div class="container">
      <form id="mapCenterForm">
        <label for="latitude">lat</label>
        <input type="text" id="lat" name="latitude" placeholder="0.000000">

        <label for="longitude">lng</label>
        <input type="text" id="lng" name="longitude" placeholder="0.000000">
        <br>
        <button onclick = "change_center()">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
        <div id="map" style="height: 500px"></div>

    </div>
    <script>
      var red_icon =  'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png' ;
      var map;
      var lat= 41.18076;
      var lng= -73.20537;
      //THE FOLLOWING LINE WAS REMOVED
      //var map=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

      function initMap() {
        // Create the map.
        var SET = {lat, lng};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: SET,
          zoom: 13
        });

        function change_center() {
          var newLat = document.getElementById("lat").value;
          var newLng = document.getElementById("lng").value;
          var SET = {newLat, newLng};
          map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(newLat, newLng));
        }

        // Create the places service.
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        var getNextPage = null;
        var moreButton = document.getElementById('more');
        moreButton.onclick = function() {
          moreButton.disabled = true;
          if (getNextPage) getNextPage();
        };

        // Perform a nearby search.
        service.nearbySearch(
            {location: SET, radius: 7500, keyword: "library"},

            function(results, status, pagination) {
              if (status !== 'OK') return;

              createMarkers(results);
              moreButton.disabled = !pagination.hasNextPage;
              getNextPage = pagination.hasNextPage && function() {
                pagination.nextPage();
              };
            });
      }

      function createMarkers(places) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var placesList = document.getElementById('places');

        for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
          var image = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
          };

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: red_icon,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
          });

          var li = document.createElement('li');
          li.textContent = place.name;
          placesList.appendChild(li);

          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="right-panel">
      <h2>Locations</h2>
      <ul id="places"></ul>
      <button id="more">More Results</button>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined` on line 110: `var map=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);` (that line is executing before the API script is loaded)

Comment: Note that the form is being submitted by clicking on the button, which reloads the page.  Also, your `SET` value doesn't look like a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng) or a [`google.maps.LatLngLiteral`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngLiteral) (although it does seem to work).

Comment: Try removing the line  "var map=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);" at 110. My initial code when ran never had that line, and after removing it, the code seems to still run fine.

Also, the lat & lng variable set still works because I had just taken the numbers set and moved them into their own separate variables to be called.

Comment: Your HTML is also not valid, you have the form in the `<head>` of the document

Comment: [proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/y1zc3qf2/1/).   Changes the center of the map (but doesn't re-run the search).

Comment: Well, the map may not update but this is certainly a huge step in the right direction. Thanks a ton for the update to this code, and I'll see if there's anything that can be done to update the map. I might update this initial question if I can't figure something out.

Comment: Just re-run the places query with the new center.

Comment: Sorry. I worded that previous statement poorly. When I said the map may not update, I meant to refer to the search within the map not updating with the change in latitude and longitude. The map certainly updates (thanks again for that by the way), but now I'll have to figure out how to have the search update with the changing latitude and longitude.

Comment: @kadiele01 are you still having issues? If so can you please clarify what you need help with and provide an up-to-date fiddle of your app?

Comment: I can now change user coordinates thankfully. This question was more or less resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920748/google-maps-resetting-markers-with-coordinates The orange user markers don't update, but at the very least the coordinates update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for this problem has been added in another question on updating markers: [Google Maps: Resetting Markers with Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920748/google-maps-resetting-markers-with-coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

for test you could avoid submit and just use a push button  than call a function for change the center

```
<form id="mapCenterForm">
    <label for="latitude">lat</label>
    <input type="text" id="lat" name="latitude" placeholder="0.000000">

    <label for="longitude">lng</label>
    <input type="text" id="lng" name="longitude" placeholder="0.000000">
    <br>
    <button onclick = "change_center()"> 
            Click Here for move map
    </button> 

</form>
```

.

```
var map;
var lat= 34.16076;
var lng= -70.20507;
var map=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

  function initMap() {
    // Create the map.
    var SET = {lat, lng};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: SET,
      zoom: 10
    });

  function change_center() {
    var newLat = document.getElementById("lat").value;
    var newLng = document.getElementById("lng").value;
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(newLat, newLng));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I can certainly see what your suggestion is supposed to do, but for some reason, it isn't actually changing the SET variable. I even added a new line for it, but it didn't help. I made an edit to add a complete chunk of the HTML code and reset the coordinates to somewhere where you could more clearly see what it's going to do. You should be able to run it with the key I placed, and if you can, please let me know if it works for you.